# Linphone Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, linphone

I am using linphone open source to make a call in my application.

I met a problem while using linphone service.

The situation is that UserA calls UserB while UserB is not using the application. So, UserB does not receive this call and the server returns call error to UserA.

Bit, I want the UserB to still receive a call from UserA anyway.

Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Check this: http://linphone-developers.nongnu.narkive.com/DGZAr7BP/incoming-call-notification-in-ios-when-app-in-background

Answer (score 0):

Solution: instruct UserB to install and use the Linphone application.